# Issues with z-index and image positioning

Tags: html, css, z-index

[My-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOKw8.png)I want to hide the half image behind the feature part of webpage.[Output-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR1q7.png)

Here is the  HTML code :

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="title-heading">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn btn-primary btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn btn-outline-light download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>Download</button>
     </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img class="img-1" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 

 <section id="features">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="heading-features">Easy to use.</h3>
        <p class="para-features">So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="heading-features">Elite Clientele.</h3>
        <p class="para-features">We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fa fa-heart fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="heading-features">Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p class="para-features">Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>  
  </section>
```

And the css code which goes along with them :

```
.img-1{
    width: 60%;
    transform:rotate(25deg); 
    position: absolute;

#features{
    padding: 7% 15%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
```

However after using the code the image part gets hidden but not in the way I want. It hides most part of the image but I want only part at the bottom to be hidden.

Image needs to be positioned that only bottom part is not visible.

Comment: this is because the image positioning is absolute

Comment: Ya but if I change the image position to absolute it would get misplaced.

Comment: can you please show the image and show the part you want to hide? because it will more easy if we could have reference.

Comment: Updated the images for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to provide proper padding for the image section and it worked.

Nevertheless thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{margin: 0;}
.section {
background: red;
display: block;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.section img {
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
bottom: -180px;
right: 100px;
transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/GRfQXS3/1559123552-1482834.png">

</div>
```

Here is the solution of your problem. Follow the css structure.